# How to sum dtype: timedelta64[ns] in pandas/Python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

I am using pands in python to deal with times. 
I would like to sum up the time elapsed between a couple of dates, which are:

```
0   2012-03-06 14:22:00
0   2012-06-02 11:29:00


1   2012-04-16 20:51:00
1   2012-04-28 09:57:00
```

To do this, I calculate the time elapsed between the first 2 dates indexed with 0 like this :

```
dt0 = df.end[0] - df.start[0]  
out: 87 days 21:07:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

and the same between the next 2 dates like:

```
dt1 = df.end[1] - df.start[1]  
out: 11 days 13:06:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Which works fine, but when I sum the two times :

```
dt2 = dt1 + dt0
```

I get dt2 = NaT instead of the sum of 87 days 21:07:00 + 11 days 13:06:00. Can anyone help?

Below is a screenshot of another example of the same problem: adding up a and b, two dtype: timedelta64[ns] does not work, why?

[image]

Comment: sorry, it was a typo. yes!

Comment: I get `Timedelta('99 days 10:13:00')`? Can you check `dt1` and `dt0` just before that calculation to ensure you haven't overwritten them?

Comment: I am sure about dt1 and dt0 though :/

Comment: I get dt2 = NaT

Comment: Can you try explicitly recasting `dt1` and `dt0` as `np.timedelta64()` before summing? Those numpy objects should be able to be added...if you get an error with `dt2 = np.timedelta64(dt0) + np.timedelta64(dt1)` then you should try updating numpy.

Comment: When I try it I get this error: ValueError: Could not convert object to NumPy timedelta

Comment: well what is the output of `print(dt1, type(dt1), dt0, type(dt0))` on the line exactly before the addition?

Comment: both are dtype: timedelta64[ns]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, this is why I explicitly wanted you to print the types. `dt1` and `dt0` are NOT `<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta'>`, they are `pandas.Series`.

When you add two `Series` it aligns based on index. Since `dt1` and `dt2` do not share the same index, it fills the missing values with a null-value (`NaT` in this case) and then performs the addition. By default it does not ignore null values when performing the addition, so what you are seeing is `x + NaT = NaT` which is how the math works.

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.Series(pd.Timedelta(1,'d'), index=[21005])
#21005   1 days
#dtype: timedelta64[ns]

b = pd.Series(pd.Timedelta(2,'d'), index=[16992])
#16992   2 days
#dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

#### Code

Addition will align on indices. They share no indices so you get `NaT`.

```
a+b
#16992   NaT
#21005   NaT
#dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

What you really want to do is add the values, regardless of index:

```
a.values+b.values
#array([259200000000000], dtype='timedelta64[ns]')
```

But really you should change your code so that `dt0` and `dt1` are just the values if you actually have no need for the `pd.Series`.